# Get the real real requested URL using IIS7

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-7

Using ASP.Net, I am trying to determine the actual URL requested by the user.  For example if I type the following into my address bar:

```
http://mysite/////one//two
```

Fiddler shows me that this is the URL being sent over the wire however by the time it reaches ASP.Net all of the variables in HttpContext.Current.Request are showing this URL:

```
http://mysite/one/two
```

The IIS logs show the same cleaned up version of the URL as ASP.Net.  This causes some of the relative links on the site to break so I would like to at least detect and log these requests.  I am using IIS7 on Windows 7 and .Net 3.5 SP1.

What is doing this translation and how can I find out the original URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original URL can be reconstructed using `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_URL"]` which has the original unprocessed path.